# I get an errorat at qresorc=provider.get_backend('ibmq_oslo')

Tags: python, qiskit

I try to run a simple quantum circuit on a quantum computer ('ibmq_oslo') and I get an error at `qresorc=provider.get_backend('ibmq_oslo')`.
I verified that `ibmq_oslo` is in my resources list from my IBM quantum account.

Here it is the code:

```
from qiskit import *  
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
circuit.h(0)  
circuit.cx(0, 1)  
circuit.draw()  
simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')  
result = execute(circuit, backend=simulator).result()  

from qiskit .tools.visualization import plot_histogram  
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))  

from qiskit import IBMQ  
provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')  
qresorc = provider.get_backend('ibmq_oslo')
```

```
QiskitBackendNotFoundError                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 qresorc=provider.get_backend('ibmq_oslo')

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\provider.py:55, in  
ProviderV1.get_backend(self, name, **kwargs)
     53     raise QiskitBackendNotFoundError("More than one backend matches the criteria")
     54 if not backends:
---> 55     raise QiskitBackendNotFoundError("No backend matches the criteria")
     57 return backends[0]

QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the criteria'
```

Comment: Please add the `python` tag. It will help StackOverflow better sort your question and add syntax highlighting to your question.

Comment: Thank you Michael I did add the python tag

Comment: I believe that editing the code by placing a space before and after the equal sign does not fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the backend is `ibm_oslo` (without the `q`).

Answer (score 0):

*The IBM Quantum backend ibmq_16_melbournehas been retired. In order to see the quantum backends you have access to, use the provider.backends() command. For example, for the Open provider

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open',
project='main')
provider.backends()
```

shows a list of available backends. For example, replacing the line in the video with

```
qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
```

will fix this issue.